# Pandas Plotting: How can I plot multiple lines without doing it manually?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a Pandas Dataframe which I got from an SQL Output via MySQL.Connector which looks like the following:

```
    Group   Sales   Period
0   0   136471.06   2015-1
1   0   645949.37   2015-2
2   0   1414552.66  2015-3
3   0   684672.48   2015-4
4   0   71529.99    2016-1
... ... ... ...
303 119 18641.06    2018-1
304 119 18514.82    2018-2
305 119 16042.67    2018-3
306 119 15043.29    2019-3
307 119 0.00    2020-2
```

The customers belong to a specific group. From this groups I have the quarterly (period) sales report.

How can I manage plotting the development of each group for each period in a line diagram? So far I've only managed it doing it manually like this:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)
group_0 = df_4[df_4.Group == 0]
group_100 = df_4[df_4.Group == 100]
group_101 = df_4[df_4.Group == 101]
plt.plot(group_0.Period, group_0.Sales)
plt.plot(group_100.Period, group_100.Sales)
plt.plot(group_101.Period, group_101.Sales)
plt.legend(['0', '100', '101'])
plt.title("Sales per Group per Quarter")
plt.xlabel("Quarter")
plt.ylabel("Sales in Million")
plt.show()
```

Which gives me the output I need, but I assume there must be a better way. Other attempts with plotting the whole dataframe just gives me quite weird plotting-results. The attached image is the manual attempt which is good, but inefficient. So basically I'm looking for a solution attempt to get this done more efficiently. Any help is welcome

[image]

Comment: You want a line for every group?

Comment: yes, that would be the goal. There are 'only' like 15 different groups (group 0, 100...115), which isn't clear from the dataframe. otherwise it'd be acomplete mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) + [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-plot):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Generate some sample data
np.random.seed(5)
gs = 4
ng = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Group': np.concatenate([np.full(gs, i) for i in range(ng)]),
    'Sales': np.random.random(gs * ng) * 1_000_000,
    'Period': pd.to_datetime(
        np.tile(pd.date_range('2015-01', freq='Q', periods=gs).to_numpy(), ng)
    )
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, group in df.groupby('Group'):
    group.plot(kind='line', x='Period', y='Sales', ax=ax, label=label)

plt.title("Sales per Group per Quarter")
plt.xlabel("Quarter")
plt.ylabel("Sales in Million")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample `df`:

```
    Group          Sales     Period
0       0  221993.171090 2015-03-31
1       0  870732.306177 2015-06-30
2       0  206719.155339 2015-09-30
3       0  918610.907938 2015-12-31
4       1  488411.188795 2015-03-31
5       1  611743.862903 2015-06-30
6       1  765907.856480 2015-09-30
7       1  518417.987873 2015-12-31
8       2  296800.501576 2015-03-31
9       2  187721.228661 2015-06-30
10      2   80741.268765 2015-09-30
11      2  738440.296199 2015-12-31
```

Sample Figure:

[image: Sample Figure]

Comment: Thank you very much @Henry. I really apprechiate it